# jQuery hide div if parent has no list items

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet which works correctly and hides the .currencybox div if there are no list items inside of it.

```
jQuery(".currencybox:not(:has(li))").hide();
```

How could I change this so that it hides a div called .currencycontainer if the .currencybox div does not have any list elements?

Comment: Please could you post your HTML in the question?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(".currencybox:not(:has(li))").each(function(){
    $(this).closest('.currencycontainer ').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.currencybox').children('li').length == 0)
{
$('.currencycontainer').hide();

}
```

might it will help

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="currencycontainer" >currencycontainer</div>
    <div class="currencybox" >currencybox
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="currencycontainer" >currencycontainer</div>
    <div class="currencybox" >currencybox
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".currencybox:not(:has(li))").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.currencycontainer ').hide();
});
```

See demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WJd2/).